# Why do I get "IndexError: list index out of range"?

Tags: python, json, list

I know there are a lot of threads for this error but I studied a lot of them and still cannot understand. I managed to have the data parsed from (a weird formatting of) json to python like this:

```
data = ....all my json data
```

The whole idea is that i have 6 blocks of 72 trials each. I want to seperate them in three lists. 1 and 2 blocks go in the first list, 3 and 4 to the second list and 5 and 6 go to the third. All blocks are 7 in json thats why i start the for-loop from 1.
This is my code after imporitng all my data to the above variable:

```
    high_trials=[]
    medium_trials=[]
    low_trials=[]

for i in range(0,len(data)-1): #parse all the participant's experiment json objects

    blocks = data[i].get("json").get("blocks")  #parse each experiments "blocks" json object

    for j in range(1, len(blocks)-1):   #6 blocks (7 blocks expept block 0 which is the training block and it should be excluded)

        for k in range(0,71):     #72 trials each block
            if (j<=2):
                high_trials.append(blocks[j][k])  #gather all the HIGH contigency trials of this block
            elif (j<=4):
                medium_trials.append(blocks[j][k])  #gather all the MEDIUM contigency trials of this block
            else:
                low_trials.append(blocks[j][k]) #gather all the LOW contigency trials of this block
```

high_trials and medium_trials work like a charm. They gather all the trials i want. For some reason at the i=5 and j=5 and k=65 I get this error:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\res-cog-exp.py", line 75285, in <module>
low_trials.append(blocks[j][k])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I am wondering if this a problem of my huge data. I located this data and seems correct, but then again why the error is about index out of range? It is a list right? lso why the other 2 lists work? Is there a problem on my memory? I dont think so. Probabely it is a problem on the logic? like i,j and k indexes? I couldn't figure out.

Thank you all for your help :)

Comment: Can you also post your json please?

Comment: `blocks[j][k]` is being given values for j and k which does not exist. That's really what that message means. Also, just fyi, `range(0,71):` goes from 0-70, making it 71 trials. range is right exclusive.

Comment: You should `print(j,k)` before the offending line so you can check which values fail. Perhaps not all your blocks really contain 72 trials?

Comment: guys thank you both. I tried also range(0, 72) and range(0, len(blocks)) and range(0, len(data)) i remember this but now im trying a lot :)

Comment: @TimPietzcker thank you dear. i printed it. it just sopson i=5 j=5 k=65. It has more trials. Also if i make a try catch exception it doesn't parse anything more until the end :(

Comment: @SamZiggler this is my json for i=4 ( i have 18 of this shitty objects): https://pastebin.com/xZHj9giD

Comment: @ParitoshSingh dear this helps a lot. how is that possible though? :(

Comment: i,j,k -
5 5 45 -
5 5 46 -
5 5 47-
5 5 48 -
5 5 49-
5 5 50-
5 5 51-
5 5 52-
5 5 53-
5 5 54-
5 5 55-
5 5 56-
5 5 57-
5 5 58-
5 5 59-
5 5 60-
5 5 61-
5 5 62-
5 5 63-
5 5 64
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\res-cog-exp.py", line 75285, in <module>
    low_trials.append(blocks[j][k])
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: can you give us either all 18 objects, or the object in question, i=5? @mehmet

Comment: yes i failed to do that: i give you the object on i=5 here: https://pastebin.com/mksgdXfn and i see for some reason that they rre not 72 trials... thank you guys :) @ParitoshSingh   i should make it until each blocks length